# Page with 2 jquery sliders (one fullscreen background, one in content) conflicting only in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, slider, conflict

For a project I am trying to get a fullscreen background slider (Backstretch) and another slider in the content(ResponsiveSlides).

These play very nicely in all browser except for Chrome and Chromium.

Project link: http://klanten.icu-media.net/wittehoeve

```
<script src="Jscripts/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Jscripts/jquery.backstretch.js"></script>
<script src="Jscripts/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
<script src="Jscripts/jquery.flexnav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
onresize=onload=function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $("#MainContent").insertAfter($("#ImageSlider"));
        $("#Menu").insertBefore($("#TopBanner"));
    } else {
        $("#MainContent").insertBefore($("#ImageSlider"));
        $("#Menu").insertBefore($("#Footer"));
    }
};
</script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                $(".flexnav").flexNav();
            });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($){
     $.backstretch([
      "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg",
      "img/LayoutPhoto/PoortBackground.jpg",
      "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg"
      ], {
      fade: 750,
      duration: 19000
        });
    });
</script>
```

That's the portion of html which call all the javascripts (and lives just above the end body tag.

Comment: Well if want some help, you should post some of your code

Comment: The problem only happens in the combination as on the project link... am I supposed to post the entire html?

Comment: Well maybe the problem is on the javascript and not on the html, the thing is you'll get more help if you post here some code, instead of hoping that people go to your website and analyse the source code. I just took a look and the background div with the class **backstretch** instead of having height 100%, has the height of the window

Comment: The div class **backstretch** is added by the Jquery script "backstretch"